# How do some Kickstarter campaigns get panoramic pictures?

Tags: kickstarter

I see a few campaigns get nice widescreen panoramic pictures at the top of their campaign:

- http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/iga/bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night
- http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/peak-design/the-everyday-messenger-a-bag-for-cameras-and-essen
- http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/obsidian/project-eternity

Whereas most others do not, for example these:

- https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/ysnet/shenmue-3
- http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/597507018/pebble-e-paper-watch-for-iphone-and-android
- http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/mightyno9/mighty-no-9

How can I get the panoramic pictures on a campaign I'm creating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon successful funding, your campaign is enabled the capability to have a widescreen panoramic picture.

Answer (score -1):

Simply upload a large and high resolution image.

Comment: We did use a large image 2048 pixels wide, but no panoramic result.

Comment: What was the height of the image?

Comment: It is 1536 tall as they require a 4x3 aspect ratio.